# Solucionar inconveniente de simultaneidad optimista en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo equipo , espero de encuentren bien quiero pedirles el siguiente favor que se me presenta con respecto a algo que se llama  simultaneidad optimista en C#

Estoy tomando como ejemplo un video en youtube, que tiene como titulo: CRUD BASICO CON ENTITY FRAMEWORK Y C# - WINDOWS FORMS - YouTube
Lo que varía es el nombre de la base de datos (en mi caso la tengo con nombre Prueba), la  tabla que en mi caso  se llama Cliente  en cuanto a los campos los que yo tengo son los siguientes:

```
IdCliente (en mi caso es de tipo varchar(50) y PK, en el caso del ejemplo del video de youtube es integer) 
Nombres varchar(50)
Apellidos varchar(50)
Dirección varchar(50)
```

El código que yo tengo para el botó Guardar es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Entity_Crud
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        Cliente modelo = new Cliente();     
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            llenarGrid();
            clear();
        }

        private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clear();
        }

        void clear() {
            txtIdcliente.Text = txtNombres.Text = txtApellidos.Text = txtDireccion.Text = "";
            btnGuardar.Text = "Guardar";
            btnEliminar.Enabled = false;
            
            modelo.IdCliente = "0";  
        }

        private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                modelo.IdCliente = txtIdcliente.Text.Trim();   
                modelo.Nombres = txtNombres.Text.Trim();
                modelo.Apellidos = txtApellidos.Text.Trim();
                modelo.Dirección = txtDireccion.Text.Trim();

                if (txtIdcliente.Text == "") {
                    MessageBox.Show("Por favor digite el Id del cliente!");
                }
                if (txtNombres.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Por favor digite los nombres del cliente!");
                }
                if (txtApellidos.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Por favor digite los apellidos del cliente!");
                }
                if (txtDireccion.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Por favor digite la dirección del cliente!");
                }
                else {
                    using (CrudEntity DB = new CrudEntity()) 
                    {
                        // if (modelo.IdCliente == "") //Insertar
                        if (modelo.IdCliente == "0") // 24 de mayo 2022
                            DB.Cliente.Add(modelo);
                        else // modificar
                            DB.Entry(modelo).State=EntityState.Modified;
                        DB.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    clear();
                    llenarGrid();
                    MessageBox.Show("Los registros se almacenado satisfactoriamente!");
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
            
            }
        }
        void llenarGrid() 
        {
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            using (CrudEntity DB = new CrudEntity()) 
            {
                dgv.DataSource = DB.Cliente.ToList<Cliente>();
            
            }


        }

        private void dgv_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                modelo.IdCliente = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["IdCliente"].Value);  
                using (CrudEntity DB = new CrudEntity())
                {
                    modelo = DB.Cliente.Where(x=>x.IdCliente==modelo.IdCliente).FirstOrDefault();
                    txtNombres.Text = modelo.Nombres;
                    txtApellidos.Text = modelo.Apellidos;
                    txtDireccion.Text = modelo.Dirección;
                }
                btnGuardar.Text = "Modificar"; 
                btnEliminar.Enabled = true; 
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            
            }
        }

        private void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Estas seguro de eliminar este registro?", "EF_CRUD",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                using (CrudEntity DB = new CrudEntity())
                {
                    var entry = DB.Entry(modelo);
                    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
                        DB.Cliente.Attach(modelo);
                    DB.Cliente.Remove(modelo);
                    DB.SaveChanges();
                    clear();
                    llenarGrid();
                    MessageBox.Show("Se ha eliminado satisfactoriamente");
                }

     
        }
    }
}
```

He visto paginas en internet para arreglar este inconveniente, pero el problema ha sido es que muestran códigos y códigos como los que se muestran en la siguiente página:
Simultaneidad optimista - ADO.NET | Microsoft Docs

Pero no sé cómo implementarlos en el desarrollo.

Muchas gracias por cualquier colaboración

Comment: Ahora sigo leyendo.. pero.. NO NO NO los id por algo son ID y son numeros... siempre... no hay caso, no importa lo que me digas.. es para hacer busquedas el ID, y es un numero para encontrar la PK mas rapido...

Comment: que inconveniente tenes? y porque marcaste la pregunta como asp cuando claramente es un form (que parece ser de winforms?)

Comment: Para abrir un debate sano, y jugar al abogado del diablo, hay gente que argumentaría que un ID no es necesariamente numérico sino un código que tenga sentido para el negocio. Una cuenta contable, por ejemplo, un centro de costo, un código de item... Son mejores llaves candidatas que un número arbitrario. SIN EMBARGO, un ID numérico tiene sentido también. Claro, esa discusión existe desde las formas normales y es para otro foro. Sólo no hagamos una regla lo que claramente es una recomendación

Comment: Cordial saludo Arriel necesito preguntarle por que la instrucción: DB.Entry(modelo).State = EntityState.Modified es la que me muestra el error, Gracias.